# Visual studio for Mac ignoring target framework during debugging

Tags: asp.net-core

recently started a new position at a company that has some older .NET Core projects that I'm needing to work with. Some are .NET Core 3.1, some are .NET Core 2.2.  I use a Mac, have Visual Studio for Mac IDE.

I've installed several versions of .NET on the machine.  The .net core 3.1 installation (correctly) went into  /usr/local/share/dotnet/64, but the .net core 2.2 was (incorrectly) placed directly into /usr/local/share/dotnet which is the arm version and that didn't work at all. So I manually moved 2.2 into the x64 directory.

Now the 2.2 project compiles just fine against 2.2 when I point to the dotnet executable in x64, but the problem I have is when I actually run the debugger it uses the 3.1 libraries (I can see this in the build output) and there apparently was a breaking change between the two with respect to the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment, get_HostingEnvironment() is now gone)

I can't for the life of me get it to use the 2.2 framework when debugging to run this project.  Eventually of course I'd like to upgrade all these projects to the 21st century but I just got here and getting them running on my local machine as-is is the current focus.  I suspect were I to uninstall 3.1, it would run using the 2.2 framework but I need to work with these projects in parallel and can't constantly install/reinstall.

I tried seeing if I could just host 2.2 alone in docker, but the 2.2 base images are gone now from MS because of the whole out of support thing, and I'd rather not go down a rabbit hole.

According to this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection#framework-dependent-apps-roll-forward

it looks like at runtime it's supposed to use the correct major version runtime, and only roll forward for minor versions by default but that's not what I'm observing. It's always using the highest version runtime it finds in the configured path and then internally targeting the lower version, which apparently doesn't work between 3.1 and 2.2 for web hosts.
ex. in the build output
Loaded '/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.1.32/Microsoft.AspnetCore.Http.dll

when there's a version available in
/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.8 that would be the correct major version.

Has anyone figured out a way to force it to use the actual targeted runtime on Mac, not the latest one installed?

When my coworker on PC runs the same project using VS for Windows, it uses the 2.2.8 framework even though he has many other versions installed, so this seems to be a Mac related issue.